# Securing access to Orion Context Broker entities

Tags: fiware-orion, fiware-wilma, fiware-keyrock

I am searching for a solution, that the value of an attribute of a certain entity in the Orion Context Broker, which is secured with a Wilma PEP Proxy and Keyrock, can only be changed by a specific user (the one who created the entity).

The Context Broker contains multiple entities, for which I want to restict the access depending on "entity-owner".

How could I proceed to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about Wilma PEP, but with [Steelskin PEP](https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-pep-steelskin) (and side componentes [Keystone](https://docs.openstack.org/keystone/latest/) and [Keypass](https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-keypass)) you can use multitenancy to secure the access to your entities, at two levels:

- [Service](https://fiware-orion.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/multitenancy/index.html)
- [Subservice](https://fiware-orion.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/service_path/index.html) (also known as "service path")

Thus, users in a given subservice (in a given service) would access only to the entities belonging to such subservice (in the given service). Access to other subservices will be forbidden.

As a reference, you can use [this link](https://github.com/mapedraza/telefonica.security-stack) as an example to deploy and interact with the different components APIs based on KeyStone security stack.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I finally managed to achieve what I wanted using the basic authorization mode of the Keyrock IdM.